# Radio showing in btn-group instead of merging with the button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-4, radio-group

I want the radio to merge with the button, but instead of that I got the following result:

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap 4.6. What I'm missing?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group" style="display:flex;background-color:white;margin-top:10px">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active col-md-3 no-padding-laterals shadow-none" for="btnradio1">
            <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn-check billing-button" value="4" checked> Total
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary col-md-2-1qtr no-padding-laterals shadow-none" for="btnradio1">
            <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn-check billing-button" value="1" billing-button> T
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary col-md-2-1qtr no-padding-laterals shadow-none" for="btnradio1">
                <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn-check billing-button" value="2" billing-button> A
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary col-md-2-1qtr no-padding-laterals shadow-none" for="btnradio1">
            <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn-check billing-button" value="3" billing-button> E
        </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary col-md-2-1qtr no-padding-laterals shadow-none" for="btnradio1">
            <input type="radio" name="options" class="btn-check billing-button" value="0" billing-button> H
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I created to demonstrate the problem better. Also, revise to explain what "merge with the button" means.